# Removing page query string .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file that creates a SEO URL. For example, let's say the ugly URL is: `example.com/stories?url=hello-world&page=5` the URL becomes `example.com/stories/hello-world/5`

This works perfectly, but for the first page I want the URL to not display the page number. For example, I want a URL like this `example.com/stories/hello-world/1` to be `example.com/stories/hello-world` How do I do this?

**Current .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /stories/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?url=([^&\s]+)&page=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it like this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# for hello world first page we are giving static value 1 to page.
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1&page=1 [QSA,L]

# for others we are getting dynamic value.
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\d]+)$ index.php?url=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Hmm, with this it's not even letting me access the SEO URL, only the ugly URL for all pages.

Comment: Where are you trying the rule, root directory or stories directory and where is the file which handling the requests?

Comment: The .htaccess file is in the stories directory, the file that is handling the requests is in the same directory under index.php

Comment: This works great! Is there a way to add a forward slash for the first page url? For example, example.com/stories/hello-world/